# Saving CGImage with image properties

Tags: ios, cgimage

I'm working on a photo app that needs to save images with user specified properties such as number of inches across the long edge at a specific resolution, say 400dpi or whatever the user specifies. So, I need to write out a CGImage with the ability to set image dimensions, resolution, colorspace, etc.  I haven't yet found a way to do this at the CGImage level.  I'm currently using the iOS port of ImageMagick and as amazing as it is, I'd like to use methods intrinsic to iOS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CGImage` is an immutable, opaque, in memory image representation.

I believe what you are looking for instead is the Image I/O functionalities, located in the aptly titled `ImageIO.framework`. Create a `CGImageDestination`, then specify its properties using `CGImageDestinationSetProperties`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I've attempted to do thus far.  However, I've not been able to grok how to effectively use the properties such as kCGImagePropertyExifPixelXDimension.  Does it take a string? An NSNumber?  Maybe this isn't the right key in the first place.  I've been able to get this one to work: kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeDigitized and this one too: kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality.  The pixel dimensions as previously mentioned didn't work when I passed an NSString or and NSNumber.  And I haven't been able to find any other doc.  Any ideas?

Comment: Ok. Found more answers in the Apple doc. The image IO reference will get me started. Thx.